# I have problems running pip after installing?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I installed pip on my windows 10 with python 3.8.3 already there. The command prompt displays the message 'successfully installed pip latest version'.I have checked in the environment variables and done what was needed through tutorials. After that it stopped saying that:
 `pip is not recognized as an internal or external program or batch file`

But then when I entered 'pip --version' in the command prompt, it said invalid syntax.
I downloaded the `get-pip.py` file too, ran it and it installed all the dependencies and everything but the command prompt still said invalid syntax.
What should I do? I am a new  self-taught programmer. Help please.

Comment: you installed pip separately?? . It should come with python. Try uninstalling python and reinstalling it again

Comment: It would be better if you share all the commands ran by you. It will provide better insight.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you that you try ensurepip command first and then try to check the version using:

python -m ensurepip --user

python -m pip --version

The ensurepip should fix your installation problems if any.

If ensurepip takes you back to the older installation, use the below command to upgrade it:
python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it the ensurepip command works but the second command 'python -m pip --version' returns invalid syntax